# What causes the WordPress "New website installation wizard" to run?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move a site developed locally, to a web server. I have done this many times using the same themes and plugins, however, I am now consistently getting an error.

I am using the "Duplicator" plugin to create a package with I install on the server. When it is completed instead of the site I get the standard WordPress new installation wizard.

What is it that causes the wizard to run? Is it a config setting somewhere or a missing file? I cannot work it out!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. Missing `wp-config.php` file in the root directory,
2. Or the database that it is connected to is empty.

Your best bet to solve the issue is to read an article or two on "Migrating WP to a new server".

Answer (score 0):

The new website installation wizard is shown only if the **wp-config.php file is missing** and therefore Wordpress doesn't has a valid configuration file to use.

Check if the file exists in your root directory and if yes, check the content of it... is it similar to [something like this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/wp-config-sample.php#L0)?

Comment: Partially correct, but **not** "only" - also shows if the config file exists, and points to a legit database, but the database is empty....

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new file `wp-config.php` using file `wp-config-sample.php` and replace database connection with your connection and then try to run your code, it will show you setup wizard again.